# chef cookbook updating slow over high latency network

Tags: chef-infra

Does anyone also encounter very slow cookbook updating over high latency networks? I have some nodes in ec2 that are configured to work with a chef server over a network with ~150ms latency. For those nodes a lot of recipes are run and a single chef-client run can take up to 20 mins, mostly due to the slow cookbook updating due to what seems a lot of separate requests.

I was wondering whether there is some kind of chef plugin/add-on that is able to compress and bundle the cookbooks into one transfer instead of many separate transfers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

150ms sounds like a very long distance or a very bad connection, so I would check the network connection first.

Where are you storing your cookbooks? Locally on the chef-server or on s3?

Do you have large binaries in your cookbooks?

Comment: Hi Roland thanks for your comment. From previous experiences I can tell you that 150ms is to be expected for the distance I am talking about. I am storing cookbooks on the chef-server and there aren't large binaries in them. Even small text files like recipes and templates are being downloaded at a very slow place. I think the file by file overhead is just very expensive here. I was thinking to try and reduce this overhead, but maybe your direction of bringing the cookbook origin closer is easier to achieve indeed.

Comment: When running an in-house chef-server (version 11), I sometimes saw weak performance due to some SolR/RabbitMQ indexing problem. Usually the load was very high, too. So you may want to monitor the chef-server node and restart it from time to time. I'm not sure if this issues were fully fixed or still occur with later 11.x.x release or the 12.x.x release.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit ugly, but I ended up copying the cookbooks in a tarball and extracting them to /var/chef/cache/cookbooks in the init script that I pass through the ec2 userdata before I run chef-client. Now chef skips downloading of all the cookbooks over the high latency network which saves about ~15 mins.

I guess this is where chef solo should come in, but I prefer to have these instances connected to chef-server as I build my internal DNS zonfiles base on nodes that are registered in chef.